# Who is Arcade in The Magnificent Seven?

Tags: character, magnificent-seven-2016

As they look for Robicheaux in 2016's *The Magnificent Seven*, they come accross Billy facing off with a generic but named goon called Arcade.

[image: Arcade]

Now Arcade looks like a nondescript fat cowboy, so it's obvious that he's not an important character right from the get-go.

However, considering that the [Cajuns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cajuns) are former Acadians, a savvy viewer might be lead to believe that Arcade is Robicheaux' mangled nickname, and that he was Robicheaux (As Robicheaux wasn't revealed yet).

That, however, is a subtlety that most viewers would probably miss, so it probably isn't in there just to generate five seconds of confusion. Is it supposed to hint at Robicheaux' tendency for betrayal?

Does this character have a bigger backstory in the older film, or the book?